# How to use dynamic Names

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanna know how i can use Dynamic names in C#.

I have this, which adds a label to a Stackpanel with a Name.

```
SPLastChange.Children.Add(new Label() {Name = "gi" + GICount.ToString() +"lc" , Content = File.GetLastWriteTime(CSVPath + "Zentrale" + GICount.ToString() + ".csv").ToString(), Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10), FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, Height = 27 });
```

If i now try to assing a new Value to that Label, I fail

```
(FindName("gi" + GICount.ToString() + "lc") as Label).Content = "test";
```

It seems not to find the Name, but why?

**EDIT**

Even a Static name is not working, so the Variable has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You most certainly can when adding elements through code. However, I suspect the name of element is not what you are expecting, or the search is not crossing `ItemsControl` boundaries.

Comment: How can i then see while compiling which Names are added?

Comment: Could this be because when you create the `Label`, you're using `GICount.ToString()`, and when you're calling `FindName()` you're using `GICount` without the `ToString()`? I personally prefer to use interpolated strings, it removes the need for `ToString()` entirely. So you would use: `Name = $"gi{GICount}lc"`instead.

Comment: No sorry, my fault, just Typed it wrong here.

Comment: @Logix Great Trick, thanks i´ll use it further but that didn´t do the Trick

Comment: You don't need all that. Throw it away. Use an ItemsControl instead, assign or bind its ItemsSource property to a collection of data item objects. In the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl (a DataTemplate) bind a Label's Content - or better a TextBlock's Text property - to a property of the data item class.

Comment: Oh, perhaps it's because you need to call `FindName` from the `StackPanel` (`SPLastChange.FindName()`). Presumably if you call it just as it is, you're calling it on the `Window` (or whichever type your code is in).

Comment: @Logix Using SPLastChange.FindName() i cant get it to take the content command.

Comment: @Clemens Is that complicated? I don´t have that much expierience but want to try it anyways.

Comment: Not at all. Search the web for "wpf data templating" and "wpf data binding". Probably start here: [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FrameworkElement.Name` must be registered with the current [XAML namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.namescope?view=netcore-3.1#remarks). Otherwise the name can not be found by the framework e.g., when using `FrameworkElement.FindName`. Element names are always looked up by searching in the framewrok element's XAML namescope.
You must use [`FrameworkElement.RegisterName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername?view=netcore-3.1#examples) e.g., of your `MainWindow`:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public void RegisterName()
  {
    var label = new Label() {Name = "MyLabel"};

    RegisterName(label.Name, label);
  }
}
```

---

But as suggested in the comments, don't create controls and add them to a panel in code-behind the way you are currently doing it. Instead use the `ItemsControl` to create controls of a kind dynamically.
See [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview), [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0)

**LabelModel.cs**
The model class. Instead of creating `Label` control, you create this model. The actual `Label` is created automatically by the `ListBox` by applying the item template.

```
// All binding source models must implement INotifyPropertyChanged
public class LabelModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string lastWriteTime;
  public string LastWriteTime
  {
    get => this.lastWriteTime;
    set
    {
      this.lastWriteTime = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<LabelModel> LabelModels { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
  }

  private void AddLabel()
  {
    string labelContent = File.GetLastWriteTime(CSVPath + "Zentrale" + GICount.ToString() + ".csv").ToString();
    var label = new LabelModel() { LastWriteTime = labelContent };
    this.LabelModels.Add(label);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**